# Vertically center bootstrap right-aligned button in a panel

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap panel and need a button right-aligned and vertically-centered in the panel - I'm stumped. I'm working in Laravel 5.5 PHP on XAMPP.

I can right-align it but it sticks to off the bottom right corner. I have tried many suggestions here to vertically align it, but anytime I succeed with the vertical alignment I lose the right-alignment. I have tried `text-align:right` instead of `float:right`, I've tried `display:inline-block`, `display:flex` and `align-self:center`, all to no avail.

Here's my code that right-aligns, but the button is placed to the bottom and partially outside of the panel.

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" >
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#f37735;color:white"><h3><b>Employment History</b></h3>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="float:right;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseEmployment" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseEmployment">
            Show Items
        </button>
        </div> .....
```

Here's a pic of what I have. The red arrow is where I need to place the button.
[button placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeaH4.png)
Any and all suggestions are most welcome - thanks.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap 3?

Comment: And where is Laravel's role in this?

Comment: Looks like this https://www.bootply.com/apKGNiEvXl? just put button inside the header.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I'm using AdminLTE with I believe uses Bootstrap 3. The header ref to the bootstrap repository doesn't specify a version. Is there a way I can verify?

This markup is from a blade template in my Laravel app. I mentioned Laravel, but I don't think Laravel has any bearing on this as the correct markup and CSS should prevail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the button inside the header.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#f37735;color:white"><h3><b>Employment History</b>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" style="float:right;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseEmployment" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseEmployment">
            Show Items
        </button>
        </h3>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO** https://www.bootply.com/Z7RSrnEIYb

Comment: OMG, Moving the button tag into the H3 did it. Thank you ild flute! I'm not sure why containing within the header tag works - but it did. Save my life!